One-particle coupling coefficient in CI
I'm learning about analytical gradients in CI theory and I ran into a problem while reading Sherrill's notes (http://vergil.chemistry.gatech.edu/notes/cigrad/cigrad.pdf). For the one-particle coupling coefficient $\gamma^{IJ}_{pq}$ defined in Eq. (10) as
$$
\gamma^{IJ}_{pq} = \langle \Phi_I | \hat{E}_{pq} | \Phi_J \rangle
$$
I cannot get its property in Eq. (13) (this permutational symmetry was used later in Eq. (30) to simplify the expression of the derivative):
$$
\gamma^{IJ}_{pq} = (\gamma^{JI}_{qp})^*
$$
Instead, I got
$$
\gamma^{IJ}_{pq} = -(\gamma^{JI}_{qp})^*
$$
Here is my derivation:
$$
(\gamma^{JI}_{qp})^* = (\langle \Phi_J | \hat{E}_{qp} | \Phi_I \rangle)^* \\
= \langle \Phi_I | \hat{E}^*_{qp} | \Phi_J \rangle \\
= \langle \Phi_I | (a^{\dagger}_q a_p)^* | \Phi_J \rangle \\
= \langle \Phi_I | a_q a^{\dagger}_p| \Phi_J \rangle \\
= \langle \Phi_I | -a^{\dagger}_p a_q| \Phi_J \rangle \\
= \langle \Phi_I | -\hat{E}_{pq}| \Phi_J \rangle \\
= -\gamma^{IJ}_{pq}
$$
in which $a_q a^{\dagger}_p = -a^{\dagger}_p a_q$ comes from Pg. 93, Eq. (2.218a) in Szabo & Ostlund. Where did I get wrong? Please help. Thank you very much!

You made a mistake:
$$(a_{q}^{\dagger} a_{p})^{*} \neq a_{q} a_{p}^{\dagger} $$
Instead it should be:
$$(a_{q}^{\dagger} a_{p})^{*} = a_{p}^{\dagger} a_{q} $$
Hence you can see from the remaining derivation that these are the same. Note using $*$ on operators isn't good notation as the operation is not defined... instead you should write:
$$(\gamma_{qp}^{JI})^{*} = (\langle J | E_{qp} |I \rangle)^{*}$$
$$ = \langle I | E_{qp}^{\dagger} |J \rangle)$$
$$ = \langle I | (a_{q}^{\dagger} a_{p})^{\dagger} |J \rangle)$$
$$ = \langle I | a_{p}^{\dagger} a_{q}|J \rangle$$

Got it! Thank you for helping and for correcting my notation. I thought * and dagger are used interchangeably in quantum chemistry though, but I'm wrong. Now I understand that * only means conjugate (works for a matrix or a single variable) while dagger means conjugate and transpose (therefore only works for a matrix), am I right?

A scalar's transpose is itself, and thus its conjugate transpose is just its conjugate. For complex linear algebra purposes the conjugate transpose "correctly" generalises the transpose -- for example, the conjugate transpose of a square matrix has eigenvalues conjugate to the original, and matrix-multiplying a vector with its conjugate transpose gives a norm (whereas you cannot matrix-multiply a general vector with its elementwise conjugate!).
